# Copper Coil and Electromagnetic Induction

Tags: voltage, dc, design, electromagnetic, copper

**Waiting for answer**

1. Does mixing thickness of wires affect the Induction?
   What I mean is that I've like some 2mm and 1mm copper wires joined together.
   Basically I remove insulation on copper wire ends and then I just tie those wires. After that I just tied those 2 wire ends.
2. When making a coil out of copper wire, what could increase efficiency of electromagnetic induction, the thickness of coil  **(Gaps between windings)**  or surface area.

**Answered**

3. Why copper is most common in electronics? Is it because of it's valence electrons that makes him more conductive?

I will be waiting for your answers :)

Comment: where did you look for those formulae?

Comment: What do you mean formula, the formula has nothing to do, I know that it is Loops*(MagneticFlux/deltaTime)

Comment: e.g. https://physics.info/inductance/

Comment: Question 2 should be asked as a separate question post (but first search to see if it has been asked before).

Comment: @LadasnoVaidas are you asking if the inductance of a real coil (a cylindrical solenoid) made of N windings is influenced by the spacing between the windings?  Or are you interested in how the thickness of the copper conductor influences the value of the inductance?

Comment: @SredniVashtar, yes I'm interested in gaps between windings.

Comment: In that case, as long as you don't stretch the solenoid too much,  I don't think you will find an appreciable difference in inductance. For a fixed wire thickness, my guess is that the only difference would be due to the proximity effect that will change the internal inductance contribution to total inductance. And that is going to be a small difference. If you are interested in further reading on the subject of internal inductance and the total inductance of real coils: Ramo, Whinnery, Vanduzer, "Fields and Waves in Communication Electronics" 3rd ed, p.186 and onward.

Comment: Just to add that I just saw the pictures you linked in Andy Akas' answer and that it not exactly what I had in mind with 'spacing between the windings'. Nevertheless, Ramo Whinnery and Vanduzer consider as an example the coil you've shown in the second photo. It's at page 194 of the third edition. The external inductance is proportional to the log of R/a where R is the mean radius of the coil and a is half the thickness of the bundle of wires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

induction: When magnetic field changes, no matter what's the reason of the change, a simultaneous electric field exists. Induction happens in magnetic field, it's one of the basic relations between magnetic and electric field.

Some common reasons for a change in a magnetic field:

- someone moves a magnet or a wire or coil which has current
- the observer of a magnetic field moves, he sees an electric field
- current in a wire or coil changes

As you know, metallic  coils  are often used to create the changing magnetic field, but the induction happens in the field, it's as well outside the coil. As said, no coil is needed to make induction to happen, a changing magnetic field is enough.

If a wire is in electric field, a voltage is generated between the ends of the wire. Electric field created by induction is circularly around the lines of the magnetic field. That's why a coil is useful to collect substantial voltage. The thickness of the wire isn't essential, the voltage depends on the strength of the generated electric field and how long wire there's placed along the electric field. In transformers the voltage is proportional to the number of turns in a winding.

It's useful to make tight windings to get intensive magnetic fields and catch effectively power from the electric field caused by induction. Transformer and electric machine engineering is very much an art of these. As well one wants to keep the winding resistance low to keep losses low and have low cost materials which are easy to work with. Minimizing total costs guides us to have windings made of copper instead of gold, silver or aluminium which also have low resistance when compared to iron.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic induction doesn’t need any thickness of coil (presumably you mean wire or conductor thickness) to work. Radio waves rely on electric fields and magnetic fields interacting via induction and there’s no wires involved hence why it’s called “wireless”.

In fact, a conducting wire can be a bit of a hindrance due to induced eddy currents taking away a bit of the energy and converting it to heat so, the thinner the wire the better. But if you need to produce decent amounts of current in “the secondary” then you need wire that is bigger.

If when you say the “thickness of the coil” you mean the coil diameter then the bigger the diameter the more induced voltage you are likely to get so induction can be improved because a larger coil diameter can receive more flux due to it encompassing a larger area.

Copper is commonly used because it is a good conductor; whether that is due to more or less electrons in its outer shell you’ll have to ask a physicist but there will be plenty of google sites that will tell you.

Your third question is answered in my first paragraph but, just in case, mixing wire diameter isn’t a big show stopper.

Comment: What I've mean is like density like 12 wire winds per centimeter^3 or 8 centimeter^3

Comment: I’m not sure which part of your question that info applies to and, possibly it may be irrelevant to my answers but, I think you need to be clearer.... do you mean 12 turns vs 8 turns in the winding? Efficiency of magnetic induction is best obtained with no wire or conducting material present so, if you are talking about a transformer, you want the least amount of copper you can manage but, given you might want secondary current, you rate the wire to carry the current and live with the losses.

Comment: I don't really know how to properly express that, I know the more windings the more wire will be induced. What I mean like there's a lot of wires overlapping eachother and they were even tightened by string, that made them not be like a spring.

Comment: I’m not following what you mean.

Comment: Well it's pretty difficult to explain in words :D

Comment: https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimage.made-in-china.com%2F2f0j00inuQpTArJhqH%2FCustom-Electrical-Flat-Thin-Copper-Wire-Air-Core-Coil.jpg&f=1&nofb=1

This is like non-dense copper wire coil based on my perspective and there's dense in windings copper wire. **Loops overlap other loops**

https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimg.etsystatic.com%2Fil%2F2e8ff2%2F552636858%2Fil_570xN.552636858_oawa.jpg%3Fversion%3D0&f=1&nofb=1

Comment: Picture 1 may be worse than picture 2 in many applications or vice versa. Horses for courses. You probably need to do some research on google to determine which is most suitable for your application. Note that this isn’t a forum; it’s a question and answer site and evolving questions tend to be problematic.